# If S is a one-element set then every function which has it as a source is injective?

Tags: functions

It's a simple question, but I can't answer it confidently.

Is it injective or not? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only way a function $f: A\rightarrow B$ can wind up being *not* injective is if for some $a_1\not=a_2$ elements of $A$, $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. So:

If $A$ is a one-element set, is there *any* map $f$ out of $A$ such that we can find such $a_1, a_2$?

Comment: So, since there's only one element, then a1 will have to be the same as a2. So it's injective?

Comment: @David Exactly. Any function out of a one-element set has to be injective, because a function out of a one-element set can't *not* be injective.